# Adding Icon on ExtJs button

Tags: css, button, extjs, path, extjs6

I am using ExtJs 6.0.1

I haveadded a button and set icon on button using css as follows

```
.button_merge_style {
    content: url(http://localhost:3545/ServiceHealthApp/HealthIcons/ServHL.png);
}
```

This is working fine but as you can see I have used local path to get the icon which is dumped inside folder ServiceHealthApp/HealthIconsin my main app

Is there any way this path can be changed to root application path something like

```
url(../ServiceHealthApp/HealthIcons/ServHL.png)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
url('/ServiceHealthApp/HealthIcons/ServHL.png')
```

if */ServiceHealthApp* is in a root folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in my opinion is to dump your images into the application's resources folder while maintaining Ext's resource path convention.

If you want to style a button, put the icon into `<appRoot>/resources/images/button` and use SASS to resolve the paths for you.

```
// <appRoot>/sass/src/button/Button.scss

$imgResourcePath: get_resource_path('images');

.#{$prefix}btn-icon-el.button_merge_style {
    background: url($imgResourcePath + '/button/ServHL.png') no-repeat center center !important;
}
```

Also make sure you have your SASS namespace set correctly in `app.json`.

Hope this helps a little! :-)